# How to translate NASM "push byte" to GAS syntax?

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm, gnu-assembler

I'm "porting" a NASM source to GAS and I found the following lines of code:

```
push byte 0
push byte 37
```

GAS doesn't allow "push byte" or "pushb".

How should I translate the above code to GAS syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586591/why-is-it-not-possible-to-push-a-byte-onto-a-stack-on-pentium-ia-32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pushb` was removed from GAS.  You should be able to use the `push` command to get the same effect.  A little more information is [here](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2000-05/msg00076.html).

Answer (score 3):

**1)** `push byte` in NASM 2.11 64 bit compiles to the same as just `push`, except that it refuses to compile if the thing pushed is larger than a byte:

```
push 0x0000
push 0x01
push 0x0001
push 0x10
```

Is the same as:

```
push byte 0x0000
push byte 0x01
push byte 0x0001
push byte 0x10
```

But the following fail:

```
push byte 0x0100
push byte 0x1000
push byte 0x01000000
push byte 0x10000000
```

All of those compile to the `6a XX` form of the instruction.

**2)** NASM and GAS automatically decide what form to use based on the operand size:

The GAS 2.25:

```
push $0x0000
push $0x01
push $0x0001
push $0x10
push $0x0100
push $0x1000
push $0x01000000
push $0x10000000
```

Compiles to the same as the NASM:

```
push 0x0000
push 0x01
push 0x0001
push 0x10
push 0x0100
push 0x1000
push 0x01000000
push 0x10000000
```

Objdump:

```
   0:   6a 00                   pushq  $0x0
   2:   6a 01                   pushq  $0x1
   4:   6a 01                   pushq  $0x1
   6:   6a 10                   pushq  $0x10
   8:   68 00 01 00 00          pushq  $0x100
   d:   68 00 10 00 00          pushq  $0x1000
  12:   68 00 00 00 01          pushq  $0x1000000
  17:   68 00 00 00 10          pushq  $0x10000000
```

So just `push` in GAS is the same as `push byte` in NASM, but without the error checking.

**3)** The modifier that *does* exist in GAS is `w` as in:

```
pushw $0
```

which compiles to:

```
0:   66 6a 00                pushw  $0x0
```

i.e., adds the `0x66` prefix to toggle 16 bit operation.

NASM's equivalent is:

```
push word 0
```

**4)** The difference from `mov` is that we cannot control arbitrary push sizes: they are all push fixed amounts to the stack.

The only parameter we can control on the instruction encoding is to include the `0x66` prefix or not.

The rest is determined by the segment descriptor. See the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual - Volume 2 Instruction Set Reference - 325383-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081307/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf).