# How is the stack altered with PUSH WORD bx?

Tags: pointers, assembly, stack, byte, dword

EAX is 102 = socketcall in x86 assembly.

Here's my question. How does the stack look after this code:

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov al, 102d
push ebx
mov bl, 1d
push ebx
push BYTE 2d ;right here specifically
mov ecx, esp
int 80h
mov edi eax
```

Like this:

```
+-~-~-~+ <--- ESP (Pointer - points to Arg Array)
| 0000 | === Protocol: TCP
+-~-~-~+
| 0001 | === Type: SOCKET
+-~-~-~+
| 0002 | === Connection: AF_INET
+-~-~-~+
```

Or like this:

```
+-~-~-~+ <--- ESP (Pointer - points to Arg Array)
| 0000 | === Protocol: TCP
+-~-~-~+
| 0001 | === Type: SOCKET
+-~-~-~+
|  2   | === Connection: AF_INET
+-~-~-~+
```

Basically, does it assumbe 4 bytes or does it just push one byte? Also, if I were to push another single byte, would it be pushed to a new 'box' or into the same 'box'?

Comment: Any debugger can tell you this, you don't need our help.

Comment: I feel it's just an 'A' or 'B' answer.

Comment: In 32-bit mode, all stack entries are 32 bits wide, so when a byte-sized register is pushed it is zero-extended to 32 bits.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, that's wrong. A byte register can not be an operand to the push/pop instructions. If a 16 register is used, then it is pushed as is, without any extension. No automatic conversion to 32 bit happens. However, if the stack is on an uneven adress, you can have strange sideeffects.

Comment: @Devolus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586591/ia-32-pushing-a-byte-onto-a-stack-isnt-possible-on-pentium-why

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, it's even mentioned in th accepeted answer you linked to (2, 4, 8 Bytes).