# Assembly convert byte and push it into stack

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to tell the compiler that AL is 2 bytes variable and I want to push AL into a stack.

Then I want to pop value, telling it's 1 byte and move it to dl.
I thought about something like:

```
push word ptr al
pop byte ptr dl
```

How can I do it?
I don't want to change values in AH and DH

Comment: `AL` can never ever be a "2 bytes variable", because `AL` is 8-bit=1 byte by definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586591/why-is-it-not-possible-to-push-a-byte-onto-a-stack-on-pentium-ia-32?rq=1 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not possible to push a byte onto a stack on Pentium IA-32?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586591/why-is-it-not-possible-to-push-a-byte-onto-a-stack-on-pentium-ia-32)

Answer (score 0):

The stack is organized as an array of WORDS. You cannot push or pop a BYTE. To store AL you can set AH to 0 and PUSH AX. If you don't want to change AH you can PUSH AX and manipulate the pushed value of AH on the stack.

```
mov ax, 0102h               ; Any value for testing

; PUSH WORD PTR AL
push ax
mov bp, sp                  ; BP needed for indexed operations
mov BYTE PTR [bp+1], 0      ; Clear high byte (pushed AH)

; POP BYTE PTR DL
mov bp, sp                  ; BP needed for indexed operations
mov dl, BYTE PTR [bp]       ; Load low byte (pushed AL) into DL
add sp, 2                   ; POP
```

Comment: Op can also push a zero and then manually overwrite one half with his byte.

Comment: What happens if you push a byte by decrementing esp and writing it to esp's stored address? I'm doing that in my assembly program and nothing bad seems to be happening - everything is working as expected. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm no longer doing that (I switched to using proper memory), but I'd still like to know the answer, to satisfy my own curiosity. :-)